# Simulate data that rotate on itself like DNA

Tags: simulation, manifold-learning

I'm doing an exercise on the reduction of nonlinear dimension in manifold. I want to use LLE for that.

And I'd like to simulate data in the form of DNA, so it rotates on itself. That is, a flat surface that rotates lengthwise.
But I don't know how to do that.
If you have any idea how to do this, I need your help,
Thank you.

Comment: I fail to understand how data can rotate on itself or how DNA is a flat surface. Maybe you could explain what characteristics the data will have, once it is succesfully created or explain, what the purpose of the assignment is?

Comment: I didn't get a good word for explaining it properly. In fact I want to have a 3D point cloud having the structure of a dna.

Comment: Do you want a point cloud forming two helices or do you want every atom of a specific sequence of nucleic acids? And what does the point cloud have to do with a flat surface? Should randomness play a role in it (as in simulation) or should the points follow strict rules (as in computation)?

Comment: Yes, I want a point cloud with two helixes and that there is also randomness. In fact there is no relation between point cloud and surface, if I said it is because I also want the space between the two helixes to be filled with points which would give the impression of a spiral surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following R Code should be easy to grasp and modify or be translated into another programming language:

```
n <- 1000  # number of points
dh <- data.frame(id <- 1:n, phi = NA, x = NA, y = NA, z = NA)
dh$phi <- seq(0, 3*pi, length.out = n) 
dh$phi[seq(1, n, 2)] <- dh$phi[seq(1, n, 2)] - pi


dh$x <- jitter(sin(dh$phi), 100)
dh$y <- jitter(cos(dh$phi), 100)
dh$z <- seq(0,2, length.out = n)

library(plot3D)
scatter3D(dh$x, dh$y, dh$z, phi = 20, theta = 40)
```

The result is a dataframe with `x`, `y` and `z` values which looks like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Should anyone choose to translate that into another programming language, the most relevant function here is probably `seq` which you'll find a good concise explanation for at https://riptutorial.com/r/example/8499/seq--

If the spirals turn the wrong way, simply replace `sin(dh$phi)` by `-1*sin(dh$phi)`.

Comment: Thank you @Bernhard